# The method add(String, JsonElement) in the type JsonObject is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

Tags: java, json

I am trying to convert a `string` to `JsonObject` with the `json.org` libraray but I am getting this error:

> The method add(String, JsonElement) in the type JsonObject is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)

**Code:**

```
String macAddress = wInfo.getMacAddress();  
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.add("mac", macAddress);
```

Result should look such as the following:
{"mac": "10:A5:D0:06:C6:E9"}

Comment: use: jsonObject.put("mac", macAddress);

Comment: The information is very clear. You are trying to pass `String` as the second argument but you have to pass object of type `JsonElement` .

Comment: Add method only accepts string,JsonElement as parameter but you are passing string,string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the required result `{"mac": "10:A5:D0:06:C6:E9"}`, use `put` instead of `add`

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("mac", macAddress);
```

instead of

```
jsonObject.add("mac", macAddress);
```

Comment: I tried it before but I got `The method put(String, String) is undefined for the type JsonObject`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Gson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson)

```
jsonObj.add("mac", new Gson().toJsonTree(macAddress));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I am bit late, but this answer might help others.
You can have your code like below

```
jsonObject.add("mac", String.valueOf(macAddress));
```

Instead of using"put()" than "add()".